# hibernate annotations one to many with composite foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, annotations

I have quite big problem with hibernate annotation mapping. Heres my diagram:

[image: diagram]

As for mapping object, few are simple cause its 1...N for: 
`TASK_DEF -> REPORT_DATA`
`REPORT_DATA -> REPORT_DATA_COLUMN`
`REPORT_DATA -> REPORT_DATA_VALUE`
right?

Now problem is when I'm trying to map Collection of `REPORT_DATA_VALUE` to `REPORT_DATA_COLUMN`. I've tried this way:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@ForeignKey(name = "FK_REPORT_DATA_VALUE_REPORT_DA", inverseName = "PK_REPORT_DATA_COLUMN")
@JoinTable(name = "REPORT_DATA_VALUE", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "REPORT_DATA_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "COLUMN_NM")
}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "REPORT_DATA_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "COLUMN_NM")
})    
List<ReportDataValue> reportDataValueList;
```

But hibernate selects wrong identifies, therefore couldnt execute query. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Include the diagram in your question, and paste the complete stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem in your code. Try this instead:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "REPORT_DATA_VALUE", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "REPORT_DATA_ID"),
}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "COLUMN_NM")
})    
List<ReportDataValue> reportDataValueList;
```

By the way, If I were you, I wouldn't create a table for One To Many. I'd do this:

```
public class A{
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="B_ID")
    B b;
}

public class B{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="b",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    Set<A> as;
}
```